# Display size inconsistent on Windows 8 laptop (Dell Inspiron 17)

Tags: windows, windows-8, laptop, display, resolution

I just bought a Dell Inspiron 17 laptop and I'm having a problem with the display. I've experienced this on another laptop that I used recently. It's running Windows 8 and has a 17.3" screen. The problem is that everything seems really tiny. All of the icons and the text are what I would almost describe as microscopic. I tried changing the resolution but if I do that then the quality of everything decreases tremendously and it's very blurry.

So far, the most useful thing I've found is changing the "Make text and other items larger or smaller" setting from small to medium in Windows 8. This works for some stuff but the problem is the size isn't consistent. For example, on Firefox all of the text is bigger and so is the Firefox title bar and tabs, but if I'm on YouTube, the video player is still just as tiny as before. It's the same with VLC Media Player. The menus are normal sized, but the play and stop icons are small. I installed Google Chrome and its settings were just as small as before too. If I set the zoom to 125% it's fixed, but then the tabs, title bar, and icons are still small.

Finally, I installed some other apps and during the install I noticed that the text is blurry again. It's not terrible, but it's not as crisp as it should be, and the text remains this way when using the app too.

TL;DR: Everything on the screen is automatically tiny, but changing any resolution or display settings results in a complete mish mosh of very small, medium and large/blurry icons and text, depending on the app I'm using. I'd like to get everything equalized.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "I'd like to get everything equalized" Yeah, probably ain't gonna happen my friend -- this is not a new or easy problem.  Applications can (and often do) override the OS font settings, and/or ignore OS DPI adjustments (programming a UI for dynamic resolutions and DPIs is actually pretty hard).  Additionally, what's "too tiny" for you may be perfectly fine for others.

Comment: Well that's pretty much what I figured, but it seems like something that could be controlled with Windows, because the apps are reverting to the size it originally was. It's like there's some other setting that the apps are checking that I haven't changed. And I'm afraid I can't imagine someone not thinking that this display is too small. I almost can't believe it's intended to be this way. I also asked two people in person and they agreed.